# Why moving file with python is slower than directly in terminal?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, shutil

I am developing a script that moves files of approximately 20MB to a pendrive. The problem is that when I use python to move the files, it takes around 1:10 minutes to move each file, but moving files directly in terminal with `sudo mv fileA fileB` takes 5 seconds as most.

In python I tried the following approaches:

- Using shutils.move
- Using subprocess.call and executing the same command in terminal that takes 5 seconds.

None worked, all take around 1:10 minutes.

Somebody know why this happen? It is a common problem?

Comment: Could you give a more precise code example (both Python and shell, or the version with subprocess.call) of what you are doing?

Comment: Note that, with Python 3.8, things may be faster. The documentation for the underlying `copy` and `copy2` functions (which `shutil.move` uses) [states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2): "Platform-specific fast-copy syscalls may be used internally in order to copy the file more efficiently."

Comment: did you try `os.system("sudo mv fileA fileB")` ?

Comment: I tried with `os.system("sudo mv fileA fileB")` and a had the same result. I also tried with python3.8, but it took even longer.